# Как запустить UEFI на Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: raspberry-pi, uefi

В интернете есть информация о загрузке RPi 2/3+ с UEFI. Но все эти методы не работают с RPi4.
Цель: получить среду UEFI для загрузки и запуска UEFI-приложений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UEFI для Raspberry PI 4 находится тут:
https://github.com/pftf/RPi4

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже сам скомпилировал файл UEFI. Вот более правильная [ссылка](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2-platforms), где всё написано. Собирать, если кто-то, кроме меня захочет, нужно на самой "Малинке".